# Using reduce to concatenate array with condition in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I've been searching for a way to properly use **reduce** method of the `Array` class in my case but haven't been able to find it. How can I shorten this block of code?

```
guard let selectedPlanets = self.chart.houses.first(where: {"house_\($0.houseId)" == id})?.planets else { return }

var selectedDestinations: [String] = []
for selectedPlanet in selectedPlanets {
    selectedDestinations += (self.myAspectDestination[selectedPlanet.name] ?? [])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `first` that you have. Then you can `map` that resulting array to get an array of arrays. Then you can finally use `reduce` to combine those arrays.

```
let selectedDestinations = self.chart.houses
    .first(where: {"house_\($0.houseId)" == id})?.planets
    .compactMap { self.myAspectDestination[$0.name] }
    .reduce([], +)
```

Using `compactMap` instead of `map` alleviates the need to use `?? []`

`selecteDestinations` will be a `[String]?`. It will be `nil` if `first` fails. You can add a `?? []` to the very end if you want an empty array if `first` fails.

Comment: wow, couldnt expect more.. thanks a lot (some unhappy answer downvoted my question haha)

Comment: No need to down vote perfectly valid answers just because you don't like the question.

Comment: More like -> don't need to downvote the question(and accepted answer) just because you had the wrong answer :P